# ARM GCC Is creating unnecessary instructions

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, arm, neon

I am currently working on some software which is performing a huge number of multiplications of complex numbers. I was interested to see how well the compiler handled std::complex, so checked the compiler output for:

```
#include <complex>

std::complex<float> comp(std::complex<float> x, std::complex<float> y)
{
  return x * y;
}
```

Which generates

```
vmov.f32        s14, s0 ; why?
vmul.f32        s13, s2, s1
vmul.f32        s15, s3, s1
vmla.f32        s13, s3, s14
vnmls.f32       s15, s2, s14
vmov.f32        s1, s13
vmov.f32        s0, s15 ; why?
bx      lr
```

I appreciate it is a contrived example, and in any code requiring performace placing the multiply inside a function would be unwise, but I can't understand why the compiler copies s0 to s14, rather than using s0 as an operand in the `vmla` and `vnmls` instructions, also if it were to use `s0` as the destination in the `vnmls` instruction the last `vmov` could be removed. Is there a reason for these instructions being generated that I have overlooked?

The compiler for this was gcc 5.4.1 with `-O3 -ffast-math -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard` as arguments.

Paul R - thanks for your comment, inlining it does tidy it up, changing the parameters to const references changes the code to

```
comp(std::complex<float> const&, std::complex<float> const&):
vldr.32 s0, [r0, #4]
vldr.32 s13, [r1]
vldr.32 s12, [r1, #4]
vmul.f32        s11, s13, s0
vldr.32 s14, [r0]
vmul.f32        s15, s12, s0
vmla.f32        s11, s12, s14
vnmls.f32       s15, s13, s14
vmov.f32        s1, s11
vmov.f32        s0, s15
bx      lr
```

Comment: Does the generated code improve if you make the function `inline` ? Also, maybe try passing the parameters as const references rather than values ?

Comment: GCC bug reports go [over there](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)...

Comment: @PaulR thanks for your comment, question updated.

Comment: @Notlikethat thanks for your input, I asked because I was unsure if I had misunderstood something and the result from the compiler was intentional. As a rule it's better at its job than I am!

Comment: It looks like a missed optimization opportunity.  Note that normally `-ffast-math` is not a priority as it is not technically correct.  You are free to code `comp()` with inline assembler if the performance is important.